# Clearing Graphics from an outer class method

Tags: java, swing, awt

So I have a college project to make paint program using swing , I need to clear Graphics object and but from a method in an outside class and then draw all shapes again (refreshing the graphics object) as I'm passing the graphics object through this method .

the class is responsible for saving all shapes i draw on this graphics (in an ArrayList ) .

SO how can I do this if I can't call Super.paintComponent that exists in the Jpanel class .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a very simple answer which is "Draw white rectangle, then draw shapes again"

that would simply solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

> as I'm passing the graphics object through this method .

You should NOT be passing the Graphics object. The paintComponent() method (or any method is invokes) should always use the Graphics object passed to the paintComponent() method.

> SO how can I do this if I can't call Super.paintComponent that exists in the Jpanel class .

In the class where you do the custom painting you create a `clear()` method. This will simply remove all the Shape objects from the ArrayList and then invoke repaint().

See the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) that demonstrates how this is done.

Comment: I don't want to send the graphics through a method , the one who made the interface for the assignment does . 
I read this before , Clear function calls repaint which I can't call as my method is implemented outside the jpanel scope in another class that I mentioned before :'(

Comment: those are my class interface methods to help you understand what i mean . 
https://pastebin.com/kTx5H1Mn

Comment: I need the refresh method so when I call redo or undo It would refresh my painting area with the new/old Changes

Comment: Post a proper [mre] with your question, not in pastebin.